# Replace "{" with "x " in files

Tags: linux, command, grep, replace

I wish to process files (.krn-files that can be read as txtfiles) and replace every occurence of `{` with `x` . Is it possible to do this on the command-line?

As I wish to do this in many files, my idea is to be able to go through all the files in a folder and process them one and one. How can this be achieved? I understand that `grep` may come in handy...

Comment: Checkout `sed`.  Here is a [tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/{/x/g' *
```

Comment: Wouldn't the curly brace need to be escaped? If not, why not?

Comment: Drat! 28 seconds too late :-).

Comment: @EricWendelin: By default, `sed` uses POSIX Basic Regular Expressions (BREs), where `{` means a literal `{` *unless* you use a backslash to give it its special meaning. (I think BREs have been around since before Perl introduced the convention that `\X` can only be special if `X` is alphanumeric; regardless, they don't follow that convention.) To use Extended Regular Expressions (EREs), where `{` has the special meaning and `\{` escapes it, you would use the `-r` flag: `sed -i -r 's/\{/x/g' *`. (I'm not sure if `sed -r` is standard, though, or if it's a GNU extension.)

Comment: Backslash or not, sed is a good answer. It has gotten my projects out of trouble without my having to write a formal program.

Answer (score 2):

sed is the wrong tool for this job, but if you are going to use sed, do it with `y` instead of `s`

```
sed 'y/{/x/'
```

The correct tool for translating characters is `tr`

```
tr { x
```

Answer (score -1):

If you opened the filem then use this below command...

```
:%s/{/x/
```